# How do I build a flow or diagram like whimsical in react

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to create something like this in a react app, does anyone have any idea or library I can use to achieve the image below.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2W3Gt.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

React Flow might be what you're looking for. Take a look at this example: https://reactflow.dev/examples/